# why I cant choose stretched_billboard render mode in the script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to change particle render mode in the script  but I cant choose stretched_billboard  mode but it is possible to change in the editor.

```
ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
psr = GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
psr.renderMode = ParticleSystemRenderMode.Stretch;
```

this works fine

```
psr.renderMode = ParticleSystemRenderMode.StretchedBillboard;
```

there isn't `StretchedBillboard` option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `StretchedBillboard` is a combination of the default renderer model (`Billboard`) and a non-zero scaling applied to the camera. So, through code, you should be able to reproduce it with a combination of these two values.

In fact, look at the documentation, stretched billboard is explained as the billboard mode, but with the applied scaling:

[image]

Looking at the `ParticleSystemRenderer's` [APIs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystemRenderer.html), there's the `cameraVelocityScale` attribute (*How much are the particles stretched depending on the Camera's speed.*). There's also a [snippet](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystemRenderer-cameraVelocityScale.html) that should give a proper example.

I hope this could help you out.